# access cleverbot with java

Tags: java, processing

I would like to get the answers that cleverbot can give into java (processing actually, a nice java dialect).

I looked in the html and the function that is suppose to be in one of the javascript files should be named lCBtn()

```
onclick="lCBtn('Say')">
```

I only can find it back, (i searched for lCBtn ), probably cause it's like a min version to reduce file size.

Does someone know how and if this can be done?

http://cleverbot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Trying to scrape Cleverbot's code is going about it from the wrong end. Instead of trying to get at Cleverbot's code (which might be copyright infringement anyway), you should try to find an API that you can use.

Your best bet is to find a chatbot API by googling something like "Java chatbot API" or "REST chat bot API" and then using that API in your Java or Processing program.

Java APIs will allow you to import a library and call Java code. This is easiest if you're a Java developer, but you're limited to APIs that have been written in Java.

On the other hand, there seem to be a ton more REST APIs (an API you access over the internet) for chatbots out there. Then you'd just do the `GET` or `POST` from Java code to the API server.

Answer (score -2):

Well, one way doing that is to use a VBScript to 'manually' input and/or output everything in a textfile and then access it with Java(Remotely if needs be). It's not the best answer because VBScript would incapacitate you to use this specific computer during the process but depending on your resources and in how much do you want it, it would work.

I'm guessing that you could do something similar with Javascript instead of VBS (but better), consult with someone who knows that language.

P.S.: Since it's relatively an old question tell me if you have managed to solve it, I'm trying to do something similar with Python.